# Android RatingBar ratingBarStyleSmall only show full/ filled stars

Tags: android, android-support-library, ratingbar, android-support-design

It doesn't even show any half star! Of course, I've ready all the other questions, they contain no magic I haven't tried.

I tried changing the style to `ratingBarStyle`and there is half star but of course, normal size RatingBar does not meet my requirements here.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="3.3"
            android:stepSize="0.1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

My Java code:

```
ratingBar.setStepSize(0.1f);
ratingBar.setRating(3.5f);
```

Result I'm seeing:
[image]

I'm using Android Support version 23.4.0.
My `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are both 23.
I'm testing on a Android 5.0 device.

Comment: use stepsize 0.5 and check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove or change the `android:secondaryProgressTint`. It is used to fill the last (partial) star. This is what I get with :

```
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#f00"
        android:progressTint="#0f0"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="#00f"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="3.3"
        android:stepSize="0.1"/>
```

[image: Rating bar with partial star]

I only changed the 3 colors. It seems that the background tint is not used at all (AppCompat 23.4.0, API 22 device).

Comment: This was very helpful! Just to complete this. If you want the blue/secondaryProgressTint to be gone. Then use #00000000 which is a 100% transparent color. or a black color with 0 opacity to be correct.